# Get SMTP server greeting message from SmtpClient

Tags: c#, .net, smtp, smtpclient

Is there any way I can get the **SMTP server greeting message** using the .NET `SmtpClient` ?

The greeting message is the first line the SMTP-server responds with:

```
S: 220 smtp.example.com ESMTP Postfix    <----- I need this line
C: HELO relay.example.org
S: 250 Hello relay.example.org, I am glad to meet you
C: MAIL FROM:<bob@example.org>
S: 250 Ok
C: RCPT TO:<alice@example.com>
S: 250 Ok
C: RCPT TO:<theboss@example.com>
S: 250 Ok
C: DATA
S: 354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
C: From: "Bob Example" <bob@example.org>
C: To: "Alice Example" <alice@example.com>
C: Cc: theboss@example.com
C: Date: Tue, 15 January 2008 16:02:43 -0500
C: Subject: Test message
C:
C: Hello Alice.
C: This is a test message with 5 header fields and 4 lines in the message body.
C: Your friend,
C: Bob
C: .
S: 250 Ok: queued as 12345
C: QUIT
S: 221 Bye
{The server closes the connection}
```

Thanks in advance!

Wouter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SmtpClient is designed to abstract away the details of SMTP such as this.

You would be better opening a [socket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/600stss7.aspx) connection to the SMTP server and [reading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receive.aspx) the response from that.